# Hive: dfs copyToLocal gives "org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: null"

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to do a 'copyToLocal' from a .hql file, like this:

```
dfs -copyToLocal hdfs://nameservice1/HDFS_FOLDER1/HDFS_FOLDER2/file_name.dat /LOCAL_FOLDER1/LOCAL_FOLDER2/;
```

But I get this below mentioned exception:

```
Error: Error while processing statement: null (state=,code=1)
    org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: null
            at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:239)
            at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:225)
            at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:244)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.executeInternal(Commands.java:902)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:1089)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:985)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:1085)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execute(BeeLine.java:917)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.executeFile(BeeLine.java:895)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:837)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:482)
            at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:465)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
    Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: null
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:385)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.HiveCommandOperation.runInternal(HiveCommandOperation.java:116)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:327)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:424)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:401)
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:78)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:36)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:63)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:59)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:258)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:500)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
            at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
            at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
            at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:746)
            at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

***But when I execute the same statement using the same .hql file after some time, it copies to local as expected.*** Can anyone please help me to understand why this happens?

```
Version: Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.8.3
```

**Update 1**: I used "get" instead of "copyToLocal" and got the same exception.

**Update 2**: This file has **sticky** bit:

```
-rwxrwxrwt .....  /HDFS_FOLDER1/HDFS_FOLDER2/file_name.dat
```

I am the userwho created the file, and I am trying to copy it from HDFS to local folder using dfs option from HQL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using java for certain intermediate logical operations.
I had to obtain a

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
```

object and do a

```
fileSystem.copyToLocalFile(new Path("hdfs://nameservice1/HDFS_FOLDER1/HDFS_FOLDER2/file_name.dat"), new Path(localDir));
```

Answer (score 1):

**HADOOP COMMAND** for copying to local file location.

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal <input> <output>
```

Here is your exact example:

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /nameservice1/HDFS_FOLDER1/HDFS_FOLDER2/file_name.dat /LOCAL_FOLDER1/LOCAL_FOLDER2;
```

This is the deprecated version:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /nameservice1/HDFS_FOLDER1/HDFS_FOLDER2/file_name.dat /LOCAL_FOLDER1/LOCAL_FOLDER2;
```

**HIVE COMMAND** for copying file to local file location.

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/your/directory/in/local' SELECT * FROM myTable
```

Comment: I'm trying to run the command as part of HQL file.  The deprecated version of the command you mentioned needs to be run from a shell script, right?

Comment: I will try this code and let you know if this works for me. Thanks for your time!